# Disk space is not relinquished by system until app quits?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

We are developing an app for iOS 5.1+ that downloads and manages large media files and are finding that the system doesn't seem to relenquish the disk space given up when using [removeItemAtPath:error](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW18) on an instance of [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example:

- We start with 5 GB of available space (as shown in the Settings app under General->Usage) and the app is shown to be using 50MB.
- User downloads a 500 MB video. Settings now shows 4.5 GB available. (Our app is shown to be using 550MB now.)
- The user chooses to delete the video after viewing, using the delete process within our app. Settings still show only 4.5 GB available, but our app is now shown to be back to using 50MB.
- Resign and resume the app several times and no change will be seen in Settings.
- Force the app to quit and Settings immediately updates the available space to say 5GB is available again.

What is causing the system to seemingly cache the deleted files? Is there any way we can tell it not to, or to have the system release the disk space?

Comment: I noticed the same issue before too. Please state also the iOS version you are working on.

Comment: Do you have any open file handles?

Comment: I would have said no, but now in trying to delete a file without having first downloaded it, I find that the system does update correctly. Sounds like some lingering file handles in the download code...

Comment: Leaks has a small chance of finding the problem.

Comment: Thanks, tc, there were indeed lingering file handles in our download code--remnants of a long-ago change from NSFileHandles to NSFileStreams. The disk space seems to report expected numbers for the app now.